# Double Integrals over Rectangles

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Estimate the volume of the solid that lies below the surface $z=xy$ and above the rectangle 
$$R=\{(x,y)\mid 0\le x \le 6, 0 \le y \le 4\}$$
Use a Riemann sum with $m=3, n=2$, and take the sample point to be the upper right corner of each square.
I'm sure it's really simple, but I'm having trouble understanding how to find the sample points that I'll be using. If someone could help me out, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture will help a lot. Draw the rectangle being discussed, locating its bottom left-hand corner at the origin, its bottom right-hand corner at $(6,0)$, top right at $(6,4)$, and top left at $(0,4)$.

From $m=3$, $n=2$ it looks as if you will then need to draw  $2$ vertical lines, and $1$ horizontal line to divide the rectangle into $6$ equal parts. Each part is a $2\times 2$ squares.

Start with the bottom layer of $2\times 2$ squares. The square at the bottom left has *upper right-hand corner* point at $(2,2)$.  The next square to the right of that has upper right-hand corner $(4,2)$. And you can write down the next one to the right after that.

Now we look at the upper layer of $3$ squares. The square on the left has upper right-hand corner $(2,4)$. And I am sure you can find the other two.

Comment: Do you mean the square to the right of the square with upper right points, (2,2), is (4,2)? Because (2,4) isn't to the right, it's above.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it! Fixed.

Comment: You are welcome. It can be hard to convert verbal descriptions into a picture. As you continue in two variable integration, you will find drawing pictures essential, Or at least I do.

Comment: So my sample points would be, (2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4),(6,2), and (6,4)?

Comment: Yes, you listed them in slightly different order than I described. Of course that's fine. In my listing, they are $(2,2), $(4,2), $(6,2)$ and $(2,4)$, $(4.4)$, and $(6,4)$. Same.